# Configure widget per project on sonarqube

Tags: widget, sonarqube, dashboard

By default when I add an widget to the main dashboard on one project, it adds to all the other projects as well. Is there a way to add widget to one project without affecting others?

Comment: which version of SonarQube are you referring to?

Comment: Hi, I am referring to to version 5.1

Answer (score 0):

Dashboards are the same for every project in SonarQube, so configuring a widget per project is not possible.